# Counterexamples/Examples related to Noetherian/Artinian Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I have completed studying Noetherian & Artinian Modules. But I still lack knowledge for some questions which asks for counterexamples.
Like
-Is it true that every subring of a Noetherian Ring finitely generated?
-Is a finitely generated module always Noetherian.

And many such examples/counterexamples.

Can you suggest me some references so that I can read and learn more counterexamples related to Noetherian & Artinian Modules?

Comment: The 2nd question has a positive answer, and it is in most commutative algebra textbooks, AM for instance. The first question needs to be rephrased as it is not clear what it means by finitely generated.

Comment: A subring should be finitely generated over *what*?  A finitely generated module is not necessarily noetherian, except over a noetherian ring.

Comment: @Youngsu: thisd is true only over noetherian rings.

Comment: Here is an example of how the first question can be interpreted to be trivially false.  The real numbers are Noetherian.  It contains many subrings that are not finitely generated over the rational numbers.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry you are right. I somehow assumed that the module was finitely generated over a Noetherian or Artinian ring.